# How can I update system controls setting on container running in ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Based on AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_definition_parameters.html
It says `systemControls is not supported for Windows containers or tasks using the Fargate launch type.`. I wonder how I can configure `net.core.somaxconn` for the container on Fargate. Is it not supported at all? Or is there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above link, this is clearly mentioned that **fargate** does not support `systemControls`

**Note**

> `systemControls` parameter is not supported for **Windows containers** or tasks using
>   the **Fargate launch type**.

There is a difference between in EC2 launch type and fargate launch type, consider fargate launch type a kind of serverless, so you can use [EC2 launch type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task_ec2.html).